# Bootstrap white/blank box replace

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm new on bootstrap trying to improve my skills, i have made 5 boxes as you can see( two in left side and 3 right side), my questions are why box number '5' appears differently like not accordingly is not on the same line as number 2 and 4 it looks like it has margin-left... but has not, second question is when i'm using 'col-xs-12' i want those boxes to be in the middle like 'center', third question is when i change my phone to 'landscape'  these boxes should be (same places) exactly like it is working now on large sizes 'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6', fourth question is, i have one box 'white space' is it somehow possible to replace that with 'Display: none; or   visibility: hidden;' and still work ?
sorry english is not my mother language.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  .box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
   .boxx{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: solid white 1px;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="boxx">
            white space 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            4
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are DIV structure related issues. please check below updated code. Hope this helps

```css
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
   .boxx{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: solid white 1px;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="boxx">
            white space 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
          5
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: number 5 should be under number 4 when'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6'

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  .box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }
   .boxx{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: solid white 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="boxx">
            white space 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="box">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="box">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="box">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
      <div class="box">
          5
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, the issues you are facing are due to the `div` structure and improper `grid` layout. I have structured it properly. Let me know if this is what you require or need further changes/explanation.